# Are there other "expressions" of $a \otimes b$ that are isomorphic to $V \wedge V := \textrm{span}\{a \otimes b - b \otimes a\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

We usually define $V \wedge V := \textrm{span}\{a \otimes b - b \otimes a; \ a, b \in V\}$. If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, it's obvious that $k(V \wedge V) \cong V \wedge V$ for any nonzero $k \in \mathbb{K}$, so an alternative definition could be $V \wedge V := \textrm{span}\{k(a \otimes b - b \otimes a); \ a, b \in V\}$.

However, it's unclear to me why this definition should be unique. Why wouldn't there be some other "polynomial" in $a \otimes b$ which satisfies the required properties of $\wedge$? For example, a possible definition is $a \wedge b := a \otimes b \otimes a \otimes b - b \otimes a \otimes b \otimes a$. This also satisfies $a \wedge b = -b \wedge a$, although it seems to be nonassociative. Is it possible to find some other similar definition of $\wedge$ that ends up producing an isomorphic space $V \wedge V$?

I'm asking because I haven't been able to find anywhere a derivation of the fact that $a \wedge b = a \otimes b - b \otimes a$ from the more nonexact constructions of $V \wedge V$, such as the standard construction as the quotient of $V \otimes V$ and the space spanned by all tensors of the form $v \otimes v$. Is this because it is impossible to prove that $a \wedge b = a \otimes b - b \otimes a$ from this definition? In that case, there should be other isomorphic spaces which define $\wedge$ differently. If that isn't the case, I'd like to know how to show that this is the unique such space.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit careful here. The collection of elements of the form $a\otimes b-b\otimes a$ is not closed under addition (unless $\dim V$ is very low, at most three IIRC). You need the space spanned by such vectors. As scalar multiples can be absorbed by either $a$ or $b$, those are not the problem. But you need it to be closed under sums.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking implicitly of the space spanned by such vectors, although I forgot to write that down. Will edit.

Comment: The irreps of $V^{\otimes n}$ are Schur functors applied to $V$ , which are inequivalent, so you cannot construct $\Lambda^2V$ differently in this vein. Identifying $a\wedge b$ (from the quotient of $V^{\otimes 2}$ by $S^2V$) with $a\otimes b-b\otimes a$ is an isomorphism between the quotient and subspace definitions of $\Lambda^2V$. Are you trying to prove it's an isomorphism?

Comment: @coiso Thank you. I don't know much about Schur functors. Is there an elementary formulation of this fact? I'm not trying to prove that it's an isomorphism, I already know that. I'm wondering if, for example, I could construct *another* isomorphic space by defining $a \wedge b := a \otimes b \otimes a \otimes b - b \otimes a \otimes b \otimes a$ or something similar. If not, why not?

Comment: How is this any different from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757509/deriving-the-general-form-of-the-exterior-product-from-the-quotient-space-defini)? In my responses to you I stated that there is not a unique definition of $a\wedge b$ in terms of tensors, we can add various scale factors to $a\otimes b - b\otimes a$. Also, $a\otimes b\otimes a\otimes b - b\otimes a\otimes b\otimes a$ is invalid as a definition of $a\wedge b$ because it is not linear in $a$ nor in $b$.

Comment: You also need to be careful with what you mean by "isomorphism". $V\wedge V$ is a vector space, not an algebra. It is isomorphic to any other vector space with the same dimension. We can try restrict to *natural* isomorphisms, but making "natural" precise seems to be more than what you want.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Because here I am asking specifically for things not proportional to $a \otimes b - b \otimes a$. My question now is: is there another expression, not proportional to this one, which equivalently defines $\wedge$?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I guess you're right that isomorphic is too weak of a property. I think I want them to be isomorphic and to have all of the properties of the exterior product. I'm not sure how to define this more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (up to a multiplicative constant) the only way to do it. The exterior product $a \wedge b$ is also supposed to be bilinear in $a$ and $b$, and this forces us to use tensors of order exactly $2$. So our only option is some linear combination of $a \otimes b$ and $b \otimes a$ and only (scalar multiples of) $a \otimes b - b \otimes a$ are antisymmetric.

More formally, the exterior square $\Lambda^2(V)$ (I think the notation $V \wedge V$ is very bad and should be avoided, because it incorrectly suggests that $V \wedge W$ is meaningful when it's not) embeds in exactly one of the tensor powers $V^{\otimes n}$ in a $GL(V)$-equivariant way, namely the tensor square $V^{\otimes 2}$ (and we can check this by scaling), and this embedding is unique up to scale. In fact we have a canonical decomposition $V^{\otimes 2} \cong S^2(V) \oplus \Lambda^2(V)$ (in characteristic $\neq 2$).

Comment: You can define as $a \wedge b = Ta \otimes Tb - Tb \otimes Ta$ where $T$ is a linear transformation.  This is also bilinear and skew commutative. Not just scaling?

Comment: @Balaji: this isn't $GL(V)$-equivariant unless $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: May I know, Why do u need it to be GL equivariant ?