# Does this alternating map satisfies universal property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, exterior-algebra

In what follows, $U$ is a complex vector space. I have the following abstract definition.

**Definition:** Let $\wedge^{n}: \overbrace{U \times \cdots \times U}^{\text{$n$ times}} \to V$ be an alternating $p$-linear map. We say that $\wedge^{p}$ satisfies the universal property if given another alternating $p$-linear map $f: U \times \cdots \times U \to W$, then there exists a unique map $h: V \to W$ such that $f = h\circ \wedge^{n}$.

Now, suppose $U$ is finite dimensional. Consider $V = \text{Alt}^{n}(U)$ the space of alternating tensors and let:
$$\wedge^{n}(v_{1},...,v_{n}):= \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}\text{sign}(\sigma)v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$$

This map is clearly alternating an $p$-linear. My question is: does it also satisfy the universal property? I couldn't prove it myself.

Comment: This is a strange property. Why are you interested in it?

Comment: Can you clean up the typos? You've got $n$'s and $p$'s. Also $V = \text{Alt}^{n}(V)$ is confusing.

Comment: @blargoner I think it is all correct now!

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff this is basically the definition of a $n$-th exterior power of a vector space. I know for a fact that it is isomorphic to $\text{Alt}^{n}(U)$, but I want to know if (at least for this finite-dimensional case) I can take the latter as an explicit example of such $n$-th power.

Comment: Ah, your notation confused me. I was thinking of $V$ as some arbitrary vector space, but it would be the exterior power of $U$.

Comment: @aschepler Only if you want a universal property for the exterior power of $U^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Tensor{\mathop{\textstyle\bigotimes}}
\newcommand\TensPow[1]{\mathop{\textstyle\bigotimes^{#1}}}
\newcommand\Alt{\mathop{\mathrm{Alt}}\nolimits}
\newcommand\alt{\mathop{\mathrm{alt}}}
$
Let $\TensPow nU$ denote the $n^{\text{th}}$ tensor power of $U$. Define
$$
  \alt : \TensPow nU \to \Alt^n(U),\quad \alt(u_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes u_n) = \frac1{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)u_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes u_{\sigma(n)}
$$
using the universal property of $\TensPow nU$. Also define
$$
  i : U^n \to \TensPow nU,\quad i(u_1,\dotsc,u_n) = u_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes u_n
$$
so that ${\wedge^n} : U^n \to \Alt^n(U)$ is ${\wedge^n} = {\alt}\circ i$. Again by the universal property of the tensor power $\TensPow nU$, any alternating multilinear $f : U^n \to W$ extends uniquely to $f' : \TensPow nU \to W$ such that $f = f'\circ i$. Restrict $f'$ to $\Alt^n(U)$ to get a map $\Alt^n(U) \to W$. Because $f$ is alternating we find that $f' = f'\circ{\alt}$; hence
$$
  f = f'\circ i = f'\circ{\alt}\circ i = f'\circ{\wedge^n}.
$$

We now wish to show that $f'$ is unique. To that end, suppose we have $f = h\circ{\wedge^n} = h\circ{\alt}\circ i$ for some $h$. By the universal property of $\TensPow nU$ it must be that
$$
  h\circ{\alt} = f' = f'\circ{\alt}.
$$
But then $h = f'$ since $\alt$ is surjective.

Comment: Nicholas, thank you very much for the answer. The usual construction of a $n$-th exterior power uses the quotient space of the tensor algebra with some subspace where tensors agree in at least two entries. And it is usually said that this is isomorphic to the space of alternating tensors. So, at least in the setting of a finite-dimensional complex vector space, you can construct the $n$-th exterior power directly from the alternating maps indeed. This is very cool, thanks!

Comment: @Idontgetit No problem! You might also be interested in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757509/deriving-the-general-form-of-the-exterior-product-from-the-quotient-space-defini/4757625#4757625).