# Alternative of exterior power as a tensor algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, exterior-algebra

This question is related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850603/does-this-alternating-map-satisfies-universal-property/4850786#4850786). The $n$-th exterior power of a vector space (over some field of characteristic zero) $U$ is a pair $(\wedge^{n}, \bigwedge^{n}U)$ where $\bigwedge^{n}U$ is a vector space over the same field and $\wedge^{n}: \overbrace{U\times \cdots \times U}^{\text{$n$ times}} \to \bigwedge^{n}U$ is an alternating $n$-linear map satisfying the universal property.

It can be proved that the $n$-th exterior power of $U$, if it exists, is unique up to isomorphisms. To prove that it in fact exists, one can explicitly construct a pair with the desired properties. In the literature, this is most commonly done by taking $\bigwedge^{n}U = \bigotimes^{n}U/K_{n}(U)$, that is, the quotient space of the tensor algebra with the subspace $K_{n}(U)$ generated by products of the form $u_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes u_{n}$ with $u_{i} = u_{j}$ for at least one pair of indices $i \neq j$.

One important result then is that such $\bigwedge^{n}U$ is isomorphic to $\text{Alt}^{n}(U)$, the space of alternating $n$-tensors. In other words, one can identify:
$$\wedge^{n}(u_{1},...,u_{n}) = u_{1}\wedge\cdots \wedge u_{n} = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}\text{sign}(\sigma)u_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \cdots \otimes u_{\sigma(n)}.$$

There is one thing that bothers me and, after a quick search on MSE, it seems that it bothers a lot of other students as well. I still did not find a clear explanation of it, this is why I am asking this question.

For simplicity, assume that $U$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f: U\times \cdots \times U \to \text{Alt}^{n}(U)$ be given by:
$$f(u_{1},...,u_{n}) := \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}\text{sign}(\sigma)u_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \cdots \otimes u_{\sigma(n)}$$
be the alternating map. As the name suggests, this is an alternating $n$-linear map and, from my previous question, it satisfies the universal property. In other words, $f$ *can be used to define* $\bigwedge^{n}U$; simply take $\bigwedge^{n}U = \text{Alt}^{n}(U)$ and $\wedge^{n} = f$.

However, this is *not* the standard construction and many posts on MSE claim that this is not a good way of defining $\bigwedge^{n}U$. But I don't understand why.

To be fair, some of the questions I saw about this topic have a more abstract setting; one takes $U$ to be a $\mathbb{K}$-module. I don't have much background in algebra yet, but maybe in these more abstract settings these constructions are not equivalent for some reason. Concerning this topic and in the case of **vector spaces**, I have the following questions:

1. Are these constructions equivalent or not? Can I use the alternating map $f$ to *define* my exterior power $\bigwedge^{n}U$? If so, does it work only in finite dimension or not? (It does not seem to me that it depends on the dimension but I might be missing something).
2. Is there any real advantage of defining $\bigwedge^{n}U$ as $\bigotimes^{n}U/K_{n}(U)$ instead of $\bigwedge^{n}U = \text{Alt}^{n}(U)$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can think of a couple of reasons:

1. The definition of the alternating tensors only works over characteristic $0$ (or characteristic $> n$, if  $n$ is fixed) since you are dividing by $n!$.
2. This is less formal, but perhaps more important: you don't want to mix the directions of universal properties. Here's what I mean. By definition, tensor products are "easier" to map out of: the universal property is an exact characterization of maps out of $\bigotimes^n U \to V$, they are precisely multilinear maps $U^{\times n} \to V$. On the other hand, subspaces are "easier" to map into: given $V \subset W$, a linear map $Z \to V$ is exactly a linear map $Z \to W$ that takes every element of $Z$ to $V$. For either of these, maps in the other direction, ie into a tensor product or out of a subspace, are not so easy to characterize. Since your alternating algebra is defined as a subspace of a tensor product, this will make mapping both into and out of it "harder". On the other hand, a quotient is also "easy" to map out of, so maps out of the exterior power are easy to characterize, indeed given by its universal property: a map from $\bigwedge^n \to V$ is precisely a multilinear map $U^{\times n} \to V$ that vanishes on tensors with repeated factors.

Sort of related to 2, given an element of the tensor power $\bigotimes^n U$, it is not so obvious to determine if it is in the subspace generated by alternating tensors. But on the other hand: given two elements of $\bigotimes^n U$, it is not so obvious if they have the same image in $\bigwedge^n U$. So this is not necessarily an advantage or disadvantage.

Comment: The point in 2 can be made more formal, possibly involving the words limits and colimits, but I did not think it necessary for this answer.

Comment: Ronno, very nice answer! Thanks! The points you raised are indeed important. I asked this question because these objects arise in physics but in a very formal way; $\bigwedge^{n}U$ is regarded as a set of formal complex polynomials of degree $n$ with some generators. It is usually said that these formal polynomials can be thought as skew-symmetric tensors. I just wanted to be sure that, in the case of finite-dimensional complex vector spaces, these objects can be *defined* as skew-symmetric tensors from the first place.

Comment: So, from you answer, I get the following message: you can define $\bigwedge^{n}U$ using the alternating map $f$, but it might have disadvantages if you want to do analysis. But, if you want to give a mathematical meaning to these objects in the physics context, you are just fine. Am I right?

Comment: Question, not criticism: to what extent is point 2 basically the perspective that one does not really want to concretely define tensor products, or quotients of them, at all? Instead, one gives some kind of construction to show that there is a thingy with a universal property that is unique up to a unique isomorphism. Thereafter one completely forgets the construction, and just uses that there is an essentially unique thingy with the universal property.

Comment: @DavidM my perspective on it is kind of different. The explicit construction of tensor products is useful precisely because it makes it easier to map into a tensor product. Of course if you only ever need maps in the "easy" direction, ie the direction provided by the universal property", then it is particularly convenient to avoid figuring out (or choosing) an explicit construction.

Comment: @Idontgetit at the end of the day they are isomorphic, so as long as you're willing to go through that isomorphism (and are in a situation where that map makes sense, ie not in characteristic dividing $n$), there should not be practical consequences. It's generally useful to have multiple equivalent (but not a priori so) definitions of a thing since they will typically be more suited to using in different contexts. (contd)

Comment: For example, if you define $\bigwedge^n U$ yet another way as "the vector space with basis $e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_n}$ (thought of as formal symbols) with $i_1 < \dots < i_n$ for some chosen basis $e_i$ of $U$", then its dimension is obviously $\binom{\dim U}{n}$, which is less obvious from the other definitions.

Comment: I see. So, for practical reasons, there I can always define $\bigwegde^{n}U$ as I want (at least in this setting, finite-dimensional complex vector space) as long as I am willing to suffer the consequences of proving isomorphisms.